# SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize

Tags: xml, postman

Using Ebay : AddFixedPriceItem Method to create item on Ebay

Post URL : https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll

Postman Header :

```
"x-ebay-api-app-name: MY_App_ID",
"x-ebay-api-call-name: ReviseFixedPriceItem",
"x-ebay-api-cert-name: MY_SCERT_ID",
"x-ebay-api-compatibility-level: 1125",
"x-ebay-api-dev-name: MY_DEV_ID",
"x-ebay-api-siteid: 0"
```

Postman Body : XML (text/xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests>
    <Header>
        <SiteID>0</SiteID>
        <Version>949</Version>
    </Header>
    <AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <RequesterCredentials>
            <eBayAuthToken>MY_TOKEN
            </eBayAuthToken>
        </RequesterCredentials>
        <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
        <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
        <Version>949</Version>
        <MessageID>Request 1</MessageID>
        <Item>
            <SKU>XYZ-776040644183</SKU>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
            <Description>Looking for a sexy pj set This cami capri set fits the bill.Deep V neckline extends to empire waist.Lace trim all around the cups and across the back.Waterfall pleats fall from the waist for an extra pretty look.Slim leg capri pants with flat elastic waistband and side slits with tiny bows.Soft silky fabric with a hint of stretch for easy movement.
                <li>Maidenform Cami Capris Set</li>
                <li>Fabric Content </li>
                <li>Color Name Gloxinia</li>
                <li>Size L</li></Description>
            <DispatchTimeMax>4</DispatchTimeMax>
            <InventoryTrackingMethod>SKU</InventoryTrackingMethod>
            <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
            <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
            <PostalCode>27105</PostalCode>
            <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
            <PayPalEmailAddress>example@example.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
            <PrimaryCategory>
                <CategoryID>63863</CategoryID>
            </PrimaryCategory>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <StartPrice>34.46</StartPrice>
            <ShippingDetails>
                <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
                <ShippingServiceOptions>
                    <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                    <ShippingService>USPS_1st_Class</ShippingService>
                    <ShippingServiceCost>6.04</ShippingServiceCost>
                    <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                </ShippingServiceOptions>
            </ShippingDetails>
            <Title>Maidenform Cami and Capris Set, Gloxinia, Size-L</Title>
            <ReturnPolicy>
                <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
                <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
                <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
                <Description>Description of return policy details</Description>
                <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Free</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
            </ReturnPolicy>
        </Item>
    </AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

Getting Error : Schema XML request error

Response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddFixedPriceItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2020-01-13T11:20:40.563Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Schema XML request error.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>Schema XML request error: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize..</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>20170</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
            <Value>SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.</Value>
        </ErrorParameters>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>1131</Version>
    <Build>E1131_UNI_API5_19109898_R1</Build>
</AddFixedPriceItemResponse>
```

**I have tried**

```
 1. removing <li> tags in Description.
 2. also <Description><![CDATA[ desc ]]></Decription>
 3. Also there is no space in <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I am trying to add AddFixedPriceItem through E-bay LMS API. And to process this i am using Postman. All fields are ok. But there may be some error in my XML request.

Anyone please guide me with appropriate answer. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. Using CDATA in description worked for me.